# Undo S3 cp command which overwrited my file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I mistakenly overwrite my file in s3 using s3 cp command.

Actually I had one csv file in my s3 which I wanted to cp inside the folder in the same bucket, so I used:

```
s3 cp s3://bucket_name/file.csv s3://bucket_name/folder/
```

And now I lost all the files which was there inside folder as it got overwrited by csv file. Is there any way I can get those files back?

Comment: did you check versioning if you have enabled it on s3

Comment: Unless the bucket was versioned: no.

Comment: If CDN enabled, u can try to download from CDN cached version if you are lucky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have versioning enabled on the s3 bucket then you can't revert this change